# How can I access(read/write) file in the external sdcard in Android Kitkat?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-4.4-kitkat

Here is my source code;
I've installed microsdsvc app on the external_SD.

```
szSDCardFileName = "/storage/external_SD/Android/data/com.tmnt.microsdsvc/files/AAA.DAT";

if ((fp = open(szSDCardFileName, O_RDWR|O_DIRECT|O_SYNC, S_IRWXU)) == -1) {
    if ((fp = open(szSDCardFileName, O_RDWR|O_DIRECT|O_SYNC|O_CREAT, S_IRWXU)) == -1) {
        return -1;
    }
}

memset(g_buf, 0x00, BLOCK_LENGTH);
if (read(fp, (char *)g_buf, BLOCK_LENGTH) == ERROR) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "JNI", "<Err>file read error[errno=%d, handle=%d]", errno, fp);
    return -1;
}
```

when running the code on the Lg G2 Kitkat version, open() is OK, but next read() is failed with errorno 22.

I don't know that what I mistake!!

Comment: Errno 22 means invalid params. I suspect you are getting Err 22 because you are using the O_DIRECT and O_SYNC flags, which appear to be unsupported on external SD cards with KitKat.

Comment: you can make KitKat available to write http://technofaq.org/posts/2014/04/fixing-external-sd-card-write-issue-on-android-kitkat/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is the reason why...

KitKat, applications will no longer be able to create, modify, or remove files and folders on 'secondary external storage device' respectively dual-storage devices with internal flash AND a removable / external SD card.

"The WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission must only grant write access to the primary external storage on a device. Apps must not be allowed to write to secondary external storage devices, except in their package-specific directories as allowed by synthesized permissions."

http://source.android.com/devices/tech/storage/index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.readfilefromexternalresource;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if (!(state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "There is no any sd card", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    } else {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sd card available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File file2 = new File(file.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator + "myText.txt");
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2));
            StringBuilder textBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                textBuilder.append(line);
                textBuilder.append("\n");

            }
            textView.setText(textBuilder);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            if(reader != null){
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

- First you need to get the state of your external sd card
- then you check if there is a mounted sd card, if no sd card its found, it will do nothing(you can put error msgs here)
- get its absolute path and add a separator then put the file name of the file you want to read
- use a BufferedReader to read your textFile.
- Use a StringBuilder to build your string, it is more efficient than simple concatinating strings
- after appending your strings, always close the reader to save memory, smartphones are known to have less memory than desktop
- call to toString() method of the StringBuiler to create your String which you can use

  ```
  String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

  if(!state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
  } else {
      File externalDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
      File textFile = new File(externalDir.getAbsolutePath() 
          + File.separator + fileName);

  BufferedReader reader 
          = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(textFile));
  StringBuilder textBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  String line;
  while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      textBuilder.append(line);
      textBuilder.append("\n");
  }
  reader.close();
  String yourString = textBuilder.toString();
  }
  ```

it throws a FileNotFound exception btw. You can do the same in writing a file.

Comment: getExternalStorageDirectory() does not return the external (removable) sd card you find e.g. in a Samsung Galaxy phone.